# Package visibility on Android 11 by URI

Tags: android

Из своего приложения открываю Яндекс.Карты или Яндекс.Навигатор. Но прежде чем их открыть проверяю наличие этих приложений таким образом:

```
hasAppByUri("yandexmaps://")
hasAppByUri("yandexnavi://")
```

Но в Android 11 появились ограничения на видимость пакета. Как предоставить доступ к пакету по полному имени пакета показано, а через URI - не понятно как открыть доступ к сторонним приложениям Яндекса

Основной вопрос: как в Android 11 проверить наличие приложений в системе по URI и открыть их? Что нужно добавить в манифест, чтобы код работал как и в предыдущих версиях?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility - вы тут смотрели?

Comment: @Andrew Да, я смотрел тут. На этой странице говорится о том, что видимость пакетов в Android 11 ограничена и указана ссылка, где говорится как правильно работать со сторонними приложениями. Но кейса с поиском приложения через URI там нет.

Comment: там указаны методы например этот getInstalledApplications() так же есть туториал пониже https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9, я думаю что используя эти методы можно будет получить данные как в 11 так и ниже

Answer (score 0):

В Android 11 нельзя работать с пакетами, не указав намерения через манифест. Конкретно в этом случае необходимо прописать следующий код.

```
<queries>

    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="yandexmaps" />
    </intent>

    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="yandexnavi" />
    </intent>

</queries>
```

Более подробно конкретно про этот кейс указано в [этом](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility-use-cases#show_custom_data_rows_for_a_contact) разделе.
Не получилось сразу понять как применить знания из документации относительно своего кода. Но надеюсь, что данный ответ кому-то поможет.